# Using jQueryUI datepicker with KendoUI grid

Tags: jquery-ui, kendo-ui

I have used KendoUI grid in my web application. It runs at batch editing mode, and a date column is in the grid.

For some reasons, I can't using KendoUI datepicker to show the date when a cell in the column clicked. Instead,I must use the jQueryUI datepicker in edting mode.

But when I was showing the jquery date picker, the date can not be displayed with the format which I have set.

Following is my configuration.

```js
$("#"+currGrid.options.girdContainerId).kendoGrid({

    dataSource: kendoGridDataSource,
    ...
    columns:[
       ...
       {
        field:'StartDate',
        editor : function(container, options){
                var $input = $("<input />").attr("name",options.field).appendTo(container);
                $input.datepicker({
                    dateFormat:"yy/mm/dd",
                });
        },
        format:"{0:yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss}",

        },
        ...
    },
    ,
    editable: true
```

I have set the format as "yyyy/mm/dd".But when I focus in the cell, the string likes "Wed Jun 17 2015 15:00:00 GMT+0900 (東京 (標準時))" will be displayed.

How can I control the value displayed in datepicker when I focus in cell first time?

Best regards